# Getting "error: expected primary-expression before ']' token" c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Working on a school assignment, and I'm on the home stretch (or at least I hope). In my code I'm getting this error on a few lines:

`error: expected primary-expression before ']' token|`

I'm using CodeBlocks to write in C++. Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//declare constant variables for the filenames

const std::string inputFileName = "subscriptions.txt";
const std::string outputExpiredFileName = "expiredSubscriptions.txt";
const std::string outputNonexpiredFileName = "mailingLabels.txt";


//declare struct
struct SubscriberInfo
{
    int subscriberNumber;
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
    string streetNumber;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zipCode;
    int expiryDate;

};


//function prototypes
int readFromFile(ifstream &inStream, SubscriberInfo subList[]);

int choiceSelector();
void searchForSubscription(int subNumber, SubscriberInfo subscriberList[], int nSubs);
void writeToExpiredFile(ofstream &outFile, SubscriberInfo subscriberList[], int nSubs, int currentDate);
void writeToMailingLabels(ofstream &outFile, SubscriberInfo subscriberList[], int nSubs, int currentDate);
bool checkExpiry(int today, int expiry);

int main()
{
    //declare stream variables
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(inputFileName);


    //need to make a checker function for these two outFile bits
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open(outputExpiredFileName);
    outFile.open(outputNonexpiredFileName);


    //error checker to make sure the file is opened correctly
    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Can't open file";
        exit(1);
    }

    //read from file and store each line in a separate variable of struct SubscriberList
    SubscriberInfo subscriberList[8];
    int numSubs = readFromFile(inFile, subscriberList);

    int choice;
    choice = choiceSelector();
    do {
        if (choice == 1){
            searchForSubscription(subscriberList, nSubs);
        } else if (choice == 2){
            writeToExpiredFile(outFile, subscriberList, nSubs, currentDate)
            writeToMailingLabels(outFile, subscriberList, nSubs, currentDate)
        }
    }
    while (choice != 3);
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
}


//function definitions
int choiceSelector()
{
    int selection;
    //get user input to search for subscription or to generate report
    cout << "------------OPTIONS-------------" << endl;
    cout << "1. Search for subscription" << endl;
    cout << "2. Generate reports" << endl;
    cout << "3. Exit program" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your selection: ";
    cin >> selection;
    return selection;
}


int readFromFile(ifstream &inStream, SubscriberInfo subList[])
{
    string tempSubNumber;
    string tempExpiryDate;
    string blankLine;
    int i=0;

    while (getline(inStream, tempSubNumber))
    {
        subList[i].subscriberNumber = stoi(tempSubNumber);
        getline(inStream, subList[i].lastName);
        getline(inStream, subList[i].firstName);
        getline(inStream, subList[i].streetNumber);
        getline(inStream, subList[i].city);
        getline(inStream, subList[i].state);
        getline(inStream, subList[i].zipCode);
        subList[i].expiryDate = stoi(tempExpiryDate);
        getline(inStream, blankLine);
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

void searchForSubscription(SubscriberInfo subscriberList[], int nSubs)
{
    int j=0;
    int subNumber;
    bool isFound = false;
    cout << "Enter your subscription number: ";
    cin >> subNumber;
    while (j<nSubs){
        if (subNumber == subscriberList[j].subscriberNumber){
            isFound = true;
            cout << "Name: " << subscriberList[j].firstName << " " << subscriberList[j].lastName << endl;
            cout << "Address: " << subscriberList[j].streetNumber << ", " << subscriberList[j].city << ", " << subscriberList[j].state << " " << subscriberList[j].zipCode << endl;
            cout << "Subscription Number: " << subscriberList[j].subscriberNumber << endl;
            cout << "Expired on: " << subscriberList[j].expiryDate << endl;
            cout << endl;
            j = nSubs;
        }
        j++;
    }
    if (isFound == false){
        cout << "This subscription does not exist." << endl;
    }
}

bool checkExpiry(int today, int expiry)
{
    if (today > expiry)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void writeToExpiredFile(ofstream &outFile, SubscriberInfo subscriberList[], int nSubs, int currentDate)
{
    bool isExpired;
    for (int j=0; j<nSubs; j++)
    {
        isExpired = checkExpiry(currentDate, subscriberList[j].expiryDate);
        if (isExpired == true){
            outFile << subscriberList[j].subscriberNumber << endl;
            outFile << subscriberList[j].lastName << endl;
            outFile << subscriberList[j].firstName << endl;
            outFile << subscriberList[j].streetNumber << endl;
            outFile << subscriberList[j].city << endl;
            outFile << subscriberList[j].state << endl;
            outFile << subscriberList[j].zipCode << endl;
            outFile << subscriberList[j].expiryDate << endl;
            outFile << endl;
        }
    }
}

void writeToMailingLabels(ofstream &outFile, SubscriberInfo subscriberList[], int nSubs, int currentDate)
{
    bool isExpired;
    for (int j=0; j<nSubs; j++)
    {
        isExpired = checkExpiry(currentDate, subscriberList[j].expiryDate);
        if (isExpired == false){
            outFile << "Name: " << subscriberList[j].firstName << " " << subscriberList[j].lastName << endl;
            outFile << "Address: " << subscriberList[j].streetNumber << ", " << subscriberList[j].city << ", " << subscriberList[j].state << " " << subscriberList[j].zipCode << endl;
            outFile << "Subscription Number: " << subscriberList[j].subscriberNumber << endl;
            outFile << "Expired on: " << subscriberList[j].expiryDate << endl;
            outFile << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to build, I get that error and others like it on lines 81 and 83. I imagine it's either an issue with those function calls, or a simple syntax error I'm not seeing.

EDIT: I removed the comment block at the top since this text input doesn't seem to pick it up.

EDIT2: On @Savaria's suggestion, I removed the square brackets from the function call. I'm still getting this error on (what is now) line 67:

`error: 'nSubs' was not declared in this scope`
I'm still not quite sure what to put in here. If I just remove it, it doesn't receive enough arguments and hits me with the error for that.
Also, I am receiving a very similar error on line 69, but it's basically the same. Once I figure out how to solve the line 67 issue, I can use the same knowledge for line 69.

Comment: You do not need the square brackets for `subscriberList[]`. Square brackets are either used as random access operators or to declare a built-in array. You do not need them to pass an array as an argument to a function.

Comment: You did not declare `subNumber`

Comment: Holy fragarooni! I get a LOT of error messages from this code. I think all that stuff at the top of the file should be in a block comment.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't write so much code all at once. If you write everything all at once, you have to fix all of the bugs at once and the <expletive deleted> things gang up on you. One bug is relatively easy to find and fix, but two bugs doesn't take twice as long. It's usually something more like 3 or 4 times as long. Three bugs is even worse.

Comment: @user4581301 Oh dang, it *was* in a comment block, I think it got cut off. I'll edit it to add that in

Comment: Edited the post with the updated code. Still getting errors on this edit, but I'm closing in on it.

Comment: I get a slightly better compiler error: *error: 'nSubs' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'numSubs'?* and then this is followed by *warning: unused variable 'numSubs' [-Wunused-variable]* Unfortunately once I follow the compiler's advice it's able to compile further and find even more mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've gotten rid of those errors and everything. I'm now having an issue trying to get this while loop to work correctly.
Here's the code as it is now

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//declare constant variables for the filenames

const std::string inputFileName = "subscriptions.txt";
const std::string outputExpiredFileName = "expiredSubscriptions.txt";
const std::string outputNonexpiredFileName = "mailingLabels.txt";


//declare struct
struct SubscriberInfo
{
    int subscriberNumber;
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
    string streetNumber;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zipCode;
    int expiryDate;

};


//function prototypes
int readFromFile(ifstream &inStream, SubscriberInfo subList[]);
int choiceSelector();
void searchForSubscription(SubscriberInfo subscriberList[], int nSubs);
bool checkExpiry(int today, int expiry);
void writeToExpiredFile(ofstream &outFileToExpired, SubscriberInfo subscriberList[], int nSubs, int currentDate);
void writeToMailingLabels(ofstream &outFileToMailingLabels, SubscriberInfo subscriberList[], int nSubs, int currentDate);


int main()
{
    //declare stream variables
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(inputFileName);

    ofstream outFileToExpired;
    ofstream outFileToMailingLabels;
    outFileToExpired.open(outputExpiredFileName);
    outFileToMailingLabels.open(outputNonexpiredFileName);


    //error checker to make sure the file is opened correctly
    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Can't open file";
        exit(1);
    }

    //read from file and store each line in a separate variable of struct SubscriberList
    SubscriberInfo subscriberList[8];

    cout << "------------OPTIONS-------------" << endl;
    cout << "1. Search for subscription" << endl;
    cout << "2. Generate reports" << endl;
    cout << "3. Exit program" << endl;

    //get numSubs from returned i form readFromFile();
    int numSubs = readFromFile(inFile, subscriberList);
    int choice;
    choice = choiceSelector();
    int currentDate;
    //display main menu

    do {
        if (choice == 1){
            searchForSubscription(subscriberList, numSubs);
            cout << "test to show selection 1" << endl;
            //choice = 0;
            choice = choiceSelector();
        } else if (choice == 2){
            cout << "Please enter the current date in YYMM format: ";
            cin >> currentDate;
            writeToExpiredFile(outFileToExpired, subscriberList, numSubs, currentDate);
            writeToMailingLabels(outFileToMailingLabels, subscriberList, numSubs, currentDate);
            cout << "test to show selection 2" << endl;
            //choice = 0;
            choice = choiceSelector();

        } else if (choice == 3){
            return 0;
        }
        choice = choiceSelector();
    } while (choice == 0);

    inFile.close();
    outFileToExpired.close();
    outFileToMailingLabels.close();
}


//function definitions
int readFromFile(ifstream &inStream, SubscriberInfo subList[])
{
    string tempSubNumber;
    string tempExpiryDate;
    string blankLine;
    int i=0;

    while (getline(inStream, tempSubNumber))
    {
        subList[i].subscriberNumber = stoi(tempSubNumber);
        getline(inStream, subList[i].lastName);
        getline(inStream, subList[i].firstName);
        getline(inStream, subList[i].streetNumber);
        getline(inStream, subList[i].city);
        getline(inStream, subList[i].state);
        getline(inStream, subList[i].zipCode);
        getline(inStream, tempExpiryDate);
        subList[i].expiryDate = stoi(tempExpiryDate);
        getline(inStream, blankLine);
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

int choiceSelector()
{
    int selection;
    //get user input to search for subscription or to generate report

    cout << "Enter your selection: ";
    cin >> selection;
    return selection;
}

void searchForSubscription(SubscriberInfo subscriberList[], int nSubs)
{
    int j=0;
    int subNumber;
    bool isFound = false;
    cout << "Enter your subscription number: ";
    cin >> subNumber;
    while (j<nSubs){
        if (subNumber == subscriberList[j].subscriberNumber){
            isFound = true;
            cout << "Name: " << subscriberList[j].firstName << " " << subscriberList[j].lastName << endl;
            cout << "Address: " << subscriberList[j].streetNumber << ", " << subscriberList[j].city << ", " << subscriberList[j].state << " " << subscriberList[j].zipCode << endl;
            cout << "Subscription Number: " << subscriberList[j].subscriberNumber << endl;
            cout << "Expired on: " << subscriberList[j].expiryDate << endl;
            cout << endl;
            j = nSubs;
        }
        j++;
    }
    if (isFound == false){
        cout << "This subscription does not exist." << endl;
    }
}

bool checkExpiry(int today, int expiry)
{
    if (today > expiry)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void writeToExpiredFile(ofstream &outFileToExpired, SubscriberInfo subscriberList[], int nSubs, int currentDate)
{
    bool isExpired;
    for (int j=0; j<nSubs; j++)
    {
        isExpired = checkExpiry(currentDate, subscriberList[j].expiryDate);
        if (isExpired == true){
            outFileToExpired << subscriberList[j].subscriberNumber << endl;
            outFileToExpired << subscriberList[j].lastName << endl;
            outFileToExpired << subscriberList[j].firstName << endl;
            outFileToExpired << subscriberList[j].streetNumber << endl;
            outFileToExpired << subscriberList[j].city << endl;
            outFileToExpired << subscriberList[j].state << endl;
            outFileToExpired << subscriberList[j].zipCode << endl;
            outFileToExpired << subscriberList[j].expiryDate << endl;
            outFileToExpired << endl;
        }
    }
}

void writeToMailingLabels(ofstream &outFileToMailingLabels, SubscriberInfo subscriberList[], int nSubs, int currentDate)
{
    bool isExpired;
    for (int j=0; j<nSubs; j++)
    {
        isExpired = checkExpiry(currentDate, subscriberList[j].expiryDate);
        if (isExpired == false){
            outFileToMailingLabels << "Name: " << subscriberList[j].firstName << " " << subscriberList[j].lastName << endl;
            outFileToMailingLabels << "Address: " << subscriberList[j].streetNumber << ", " << subscriberList[j].city << ", " << subscriberList[j].state << " " << subscriberList[j].zipCode << endl;
            outFileToMailingLabels << "Subscription Number: " << subscriberList[j].subscriberNumber << endl;
            outFileToMailingLabels << "Expired on: " << subscriberList[j].expiryDate << endl;
            outFileToMailingLabels << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm mostly confused on this part here:

```
    choice = choiceSelector();
    int currentDate;
    //display main menu

    do {
        if (choice == 1){
            searchForSubscription(subscriberList, numSubs);
            cout << "test to show selection 1" << endl;
            //choice = 0;
            choice = choiceSelector();
        } else if (choice == 2){
            cout << "Please enter the current date in YYMM format: ";
            cin >> currentDate;
            writeToExpiredFile(outFileToExpired, subscriberList, numSubs, currentDate);
            writeToMailingLabels(outFileToMailingLabels, subscriberList, numSubs, currentDate);
            cout << "test to show selection 2" << endl;
            //choice = 0;
            choice = choiceSelector();

        } else if (choice == 3){
            return 0;
        }
        choice = choiceSelector();
    } while (choice == 0);
```

Comment: I imagine there's something up with the stoi statements on lines 92 and 100, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

DONE! I finally got it figured out. My condition for the do while loop was wrong. I changed it to

````
    do {
        if (choice == 1){
            searchForSubscription(subscriberList, numSubs);
            choice = 0;
        } else if (choice == 2){
            cout << "Please enter the current date in YYMM format: ";
            cin >> currentDate;
            writeToExpiredFile(outFileToExpired, subscriberList, numSubs, currentDate);
            writeToMailingLabels(outFileToMailingLabels, subscriberList, numSubs, currentDate);
            choice = 0;
        }
        choice = choiceSelector();
    } while (choice != 3);```
````